# Injectivity of analytic $f: D(0, r) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ in the range $D(0, \min\{|f(z)|: |z| = r\})$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is analytic on $\{|z| \leq r\}$ and $f(0) = 0, f'(z) \neq 0$. Let $\rho = \min\{|f(z)|: |z|=r\}$. Is it true that if $|w| \leq \rho$ in the image of $f$, then $f(z) = w$ has only one zero on $\{|z| \leq r\}$?

EDIT: $|w| < \rho$

Comment: It seems to come down to computing $\int_C \frac {dz} {z-w} $ , where $C:=z:|z| \leq r $, aka, $C=re^{it} ;  0<t\leq 2\pi $ And the maximum modulus principle should somehow come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Suppose $f(z) = e^z-1$ and $r= 2 \pi.$ Then $\rho =0$ (because $f(\pm 2\pi i) = 0).$ Then $|w|\le \rho \implies w =0,$ and $f(z) = 0$ has three solutions.